# How to return data from a fetch and use the data to another function

Tags: javascript, fetch

I want to use the data I get from a fetch request so I return it as an array. The return value(array) will be use to another function but I get a promise :

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(10)
```

Below is the complete code

```
function getEmailList() {
  fetch(myData.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/email', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(emails => {
    emails.map((email) => {
      emailArr.push(email.title.rendered)
    })
    return emailArr;
  }).catch(err => console.log('failed', err))
}

function getData() {
  let emailList = getEmailList();
  console.log(emailList)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calling code can be

```
function getData() {
  getEmailList().then(emailList => console.log(emailList));  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. I'll try to read more about asynchronous call.. Cheers

Comment: You need to return `fetch` in `getEmailList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use async await

```
function async getData() {
  let emailList = await getEmailList();
  console.log(emailList)
}
```

Comment: This won't work as is. OP's function doesn't return anything to await. Your function will just log undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `fetch` in `getEmailList()` and use `async/await` in `getData()`.

```
function getEmailList() {
  return fetch(myData.root_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/email', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(emails => {
    emails.map((email) => {
      emailArr.push(email.title.rendered)
    })
    return emailArr;
  }).catch(err => console.log('failed', err))
}

async function getData() {
  let emailList = await getEmailList();
  console.log(emailList)
}
```